# Magento2: How to override admin files

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, adminhtml, overrides, core

I need to add some modification on the following file so that i'm trying to overwrite the file in local

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml

to `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Sales/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml`

also try `app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Sales/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml`
`app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Sales/templates/adminhtml/order/view/info.phtml`

But it seems not working...!

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: @ Prince Patel Please look my full code its not working can you please check it

Comment: Replace `Vendor_Module` to `Pikbutton_Admin` at sales_order_view.xml

Comment: @ Prince Patel its working thank you soo much

Comment: Your Welcome :) Happy Coding.........

Comment: @Prince Patel can you answer for thishttps://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182283/how-to-show-message-in-checkout-shippinh-information-page-from-plugin-before-sav

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**You Cannot Override Admin Files Directly In Your Theme. You Need Custom Module For Overriding Admin Files OR Use Existing Custom Module.**

**1)** Copy `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml`

to `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml`

**2)** Create **sales_order_view.xml** at

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

and add this code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/view/info.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

**3)** Depending on your cache settings you may have to clear cache: `php bin/magento cache:clear`

Comment: i have created the module with this code but still it loading from core folder

Comment: I tested code in my custom module it's working fine. Please make sure your module is enabled.

Comment: @ Prince Patel  did you check my updated code do i make any mistake there?

Comment: can you answer for this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186141/website-switching-in-magento-1-9-without-changing-the-default-url

Comment: how to override Block files of admin? magento/module-sales/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Create/Form/Address.php.  how to override this file

Answer (score 4):

Create one module and in that module create one xml file in `view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="order_info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/view/info.phtml</argument>
            </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your `info.phtml` file is loaded from which xml file. possible 3 are `sales_order_invoice_new.xml`, `sales_order_creditmemo_new.xml` & `sales_order_view.xml`

In your custom module create an xml file like this,

> app/code/Module/Namespace/view/frontend/layout/sales_order_view.xml

In that xml file, paste the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="left">
            <referenceBlock name="order_info">
                <action method="setTemplate">
                    <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Module_Namespace::order/view/info.phtml</argument>
                </action>
            </referenceBlock>
         </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Then create a template file in this path

> app/code/Module/Namespace/view/frontend/template/order/view/info.phtml.

Then you can add your custom code in that file.