# Magento 2.2.5 Override tracking.phtml at vendor/magento/module-shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/order

Tags: magento2.2, adminhtml

Has someone an idea on how to override this template?

I have tried the following without any success:

In `app/code/Custom/Shipping/registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
    'adminhtml/Custom/Shipping',
    __DIR__
);
```

In `app/code/Custom/Shipping/etc/module.xml`

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Custom_Shipping" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Shipping"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

In `app/code/Custom/Shipping/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_invoice_new.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="form">
            <block class="Magento\Shipping\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Tracking\Invoice" name="tracking" template="Custom_Shipping::order/tracking.phtml"/>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

In `app/code/Custom/Shipping/view/adminhtml/templates/order/tracking.phtml` I'd adjust the code that comes originally from tracking.phtml in the vendor map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="tracking">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Custom_Shipping::order/tracking.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your module file "app/code/Custom/Shipping/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_invoice_new.xml"

Please update code with following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="form">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Custom_Shipping::order/tracking.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
</body>
```

Clear cache and check, 
 Hope it will work for you.

Comment: This generates an error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() at tracking.phtml:71; I think this has to do with the fact that the template cannot find the definition of getCarriers() which is defined in the block class Magento\Shipping\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Tracking

Answer (score 0):

We cannot overwrite admin files directly. We have to either create a new module for this or use a existing once.

I think the following code may help you

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Custom_Shipping::order/tracking.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Try clearing cache and reindexing.
You can also refer to this link for more details.
[Magento2: How to override admin files](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182155/magento2-how-to-override-admin-files)

Hope it helps!

Comment: This also generates an error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() at tracking.phtml:71; I think this has to do with the fact that the template cannot find the definition of getCarriers() which is defined in the block class Magento\Shipping\Block\Adminhtml\Order\Tracking

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to override template using your custom module.

If it is correct, then the code in registration.php needs to be changed.
According to your current code, you are registering a theme, whereas you should register a module as follows:

```
<?php

use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;

    ComponentRegistrar::register(
        ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
        'Custom_Shipping',
        __DIR__
    );
```