# I want to override backend file. Magento2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I want to override backend file items.phtml

`vendor\magento\module-sales\view\adminhtml\templates\order\invoice\view\items.phtml`

what i was doing

`design\adminhtml\xzktur\Xzktur_Theme\Magento_Sales\templates\order\invoice\view\items.phtml`

but it doesn't work, what's my mistake ? Thanks

Comment: must watch items.phtm => items.phtml

Comment: did you do upgrade or deploy?

Comment: Savan Patel , no, but is it required?

Comment: please do it and check again

Comment: I tried and upgrade and deploy , but it is still not working

Comment: did you add Any plugin for checkout ?

Comment: you have to create module for this.

Comment: Savan Patel , there are no plugins

Comment: @RobinioTor reference link => https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182155/magento2-how-to-override-admin-files

Comment: you can try `app\design\adminhtml\Xzktur_Theme\default\Magento_Sales\templates\order\invoice\view\items.phtml`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following way:You need to create a custom module first

**Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_invoice_view.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
   <referenceBlock name="invoice_items">
       <action method="setTemplate">
            <argument name="template" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Module::order/invoice/view/items.phtml</argument>
        </action>
    </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

Copy original file into following location:

```
Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/templates/order/invoice/view/items.phtml
```

Clear cache.

Comment: aravind, I do as you wrote, but for the items.phtml , the name="invoice_items" doesn't work , but when i override info.phtml name="order_info " it's work

Comment: aravind, it works, but you did not correctly mark the XML file, the place sales_order_view.xml  should be  sales_order_invoice_view.xml

Comment: I have updated the answer..